# Yocto parallel configuration packages files conflict

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, systemd, recipe

I have a base package that gives my functionality (wireguard-tools, [taken from internet](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/60781/)).
This package includes no configuration files for the network interfaces (as it should).

Then I created a few packages with this configuration files that are only to be deployed one for each respective image (e.g. `image-1` includes `wireguard-1-conf` while `image-2` includes `wireguard-2-conf`).

I would like to setup SystemD, but I can only do this when I have an interface configured, and it will only happen when the `*-conf` package is installed.

Unfortunately, the SystemD service file ("wg-quick@.service") is deployed by `wireguard-tools` package and my dependent package, the `*-conf` one, cannot see it:

```
ERROR: Function failed: SYSTEMD_SERVICE_wireguard-1-conf value wg-quick@wg0.service does not exist
```

I managed to do a dirty workaround but I feel dirtiest doing this in my `*-conf` recipe:

```
do_install_append () {
    touch ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/wg-quick@wg0.service

pkg_postinst_${PN} () {
    rm -f $D/${systemd_system_unitdir}/wg-quick@wg0.service
```

How should I proceed to make it work "the right way"?
Is there an elegant way of making "wg-quick@.service" from `wireguard-tools` accessible to `*-conf`?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Additional Info**

My `*-conf` recipes inherit systemd and include `wireguard-tools` dependency:

```
inherit systemd
...
DEPENDS_${PN} = "wireguard-tools"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "wireguard-tools"
```

I so nothing else worth to mention in my recipes.

Comment: First note: `DEPENDS` isn't package specific variable. The correct is `DEPENDS = "wireguard-tools"`. Anyway - you are trying to create three packages: `wireguard-tools` containing systemd service and two configurations? If yes, I don't see a reason why `*-conf` needs to contain `inherit systemd` and `DEPENDS`. The `RDEPENDS_${PN}` is enough - `*-conf` will be installed together with `wireguard-tools` on the target. `*-conf` don't need the systemd service during build, right?

Comment: Hi @TomasNovotny. This different configurations build only in different images (so I can automatically configure a pair of boards with the same firmware but different VPN configurations). I have inherited `systemd` in the "*-conf" to be able to run `SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "wg-quick@$wg0-*.service"` in the "*-conf" script (the only point I have "wg0-*" configuration available). Is there any other approach to enable systemd service in my image? Thanks!

Comment: Two distinct things: 1) If the vpn configuration is simply the conf (some text file for vpn daemon), then you can ship it in "-conf" and thats it (and `RDEPENDS` to "-tools"). The `wireguard-tools` will contain and start the systemd service. If there is `RDEPENDS`, the systemd service and configuration will be available on target during boot. I don't see any reason for availability of systemd service during build time of configuration (is there any?)

Comment: 2) If you want just a different configuration for machine, you may have one configuration recipe. The actually shipped configuration may depend on the machine (the package's arch will be machine specific then). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265618/yocto-install-different-config-files-based-on-machine-type-or-target-image/49281083#49281083.

Comment: Wireguard systemd service needs a parameter. I cannot just enable it in "-tools" since the parameter (network interface name) does not exist yet. This network interface name only comes up in the "-conf" recipe. Note that wireguard service is named "wg-quick@.service" while I may need to enable any given interface as `systemctl enable wg-quick@interface_name.service` (and it is actually possible to have multiple wireguard interfaces running o the same board). Thanks again @TomasNovotny.

Comment: ok, I see another options, like enabling the desired interface in `-tools` depending on the machine. Or some rootfs or image postprocess command. But better to find solution in chat rather than comments...

Comment: "enabling the desired interface in -tools depending on the machine"... this could work if I impose a restriction of only having one VPN per machine (and having the same name as the machine). Nevertheless, I checked my files and this images are not configured to build on different "machines". There is only one machine and different images are defined in different recipes (that's not my fault, I swear). Once more, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186931/discussion-between-tomas-novotny-and-j4x).