# Configuring custom recipe options from machine in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

We are building a poky/oe based system to run on a few different versions of a board, which have some minor differences. One example is the SWD/JTAG IO pins varying between the boards.

I'd like to be able to configure these pins per machine, which the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265618/yocto-install-different-config-files-based-on-machine-type-or-target-image) basically answers.

However, I'd rather be able to set these options *from the machine* than having to do per-machine config in the recipe. I.e, id like to be able to do something like this:

```
# /conf/machine/my_machine_v1.conf
OPENOCD_SWCLK_PIN = "25"
OPENOCD_SWDIO_PIN = "24"
OPENOCD_SRST_PIN  = "23"
```

And then something like this in my recipe that installs the openocd config file:

```
SWCLK_PIN = ".... get machine config SWCLK_PIN ..."
```

etc.

This would make it so i don't have to modify the recipe for each new machine. Is it possible?

Comment: Pins  configurations are related to the kernel. I am not an expert in kernel but I think that the pins configurations are compiled into kernel files and I doubt they can be easily changed. In any way, you probably should add kernel tags.

Comment: On second thought, maybe you can create a separate dtb for each pin configuration and then change dtbs on start up.

Comment: I need the pins to be written to a config file, and there are more options like this. I am asking in general if i am able to configure the recipes from the machine, instead of the other way around. either way, i dont think device trees will help me here

Comment: You can rebuild the Yocto image on your hardware with the extensive SDK, but this increases the image size. I don't think this is something you would want to do in production.

Comment: not from the actual hardware, but from the `machine/my-machine.conf` file. I would think the original question was fairly clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variables set in `.conf` files are global, i.e. available in all recipes. Thus the variable can simply be read from the recipe using `${OPENOCD_SWCLK_PIN}`

What caught me off guard was that bitbake expands the variables in inline shell scripts instead of setting them in the environment, and bitbake requires the braces in `${XXX}`.

```sh
do_install() {
  # echo "$OPENOCD_SWCLK_PIN" >> ${D}/some_file.cfg # WONT WORK
  echo "${OPENOCD_SWCLK_PIN}" >> ${D}/some_file.cfg # Works,
  # OPENOCD_CWCLK_PIN can be set in the recipe file, distro.conf or machine.conf etc.
}
```

Thanks to paulbarker on irc for explaining the issue.